# Garbage collection in Android app causing UI thread to freeze. Caused by object creation - is object pooling the answer?

Tags: android, multithreading, memory-management, garbage-collection, ros

I have inherited a rather large code base that includes a number of external libraries, and am completely new to java/android/app development; sorry if some of my terminology is off or I am missing necessary information.

I have an application that has a display thread that uses unity (com.unity3d.player). Additionally, in what I believe to be a background thread, the application subscribes to ROS messages (using the external ROSjava/rosandroid libraries, although pulled in locally with some small modification). This causes a **large amount of object creation**, I think all coming from reading the ROS messages (and deserializing, putting the data in hashmaps, and later getting it) which **leads to a lot of garbage collection**, which freezes the app. I eventually get a "suspending all threads" message.

I note that the application is not maxing out at a lot of memory, so I was wondering if there was a way to force it to allocate more memory rapidly instead of garbage collecting and freezing. In searching I have also come across object pooling as a solution to this problem, but have also found people saying this just interferes with GC unnecessarily; **could adding object pooling in the message reading portion help my situation**? I know I would need to implement this in such a way that the data was still buffering correctly so it wouldn't be lost, somehow.

Thanks for any advice you can provide. Here are some screenshots showing the memory allocation problem threads.

[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLfMU.png)

[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzvyY.png)

Comment: How did you determine that it was garbage collection that causes the app to freeze?

Comment: I get a "suspending all threads.\n Mark sweep GC" message, and I can see the GC running frequently in the android monitor. When not sending messages, the app never freezes.

Comment: Avoiding garbage generation will certainly reduce the overhead of garbage collection. Object pooling can certainly be beneficial. Tools like the [allocation tracker](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-allocation.html) can help identify the source of high-frequency allocations. ([here too](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/allocation-tracker-walkthru.html))

Comment: I believe this is what I have shown in my screenshots. I guess I need to dive in to how to keep the data buffered while using the object pool.